# Android Firebase storage SDK maximum parallel uploads

Tags: android, multithreading, image, firebase-storage, image-upload

I have to upload some hundreds of photos to Firebase Storage. All the images are 10-15KB. I followed the suggestions and sent them 10 by 10. The problem is that the SDK seem to work only with 2 parallel threads. 
It actually doesn't matter if I send 10 requests or 2, only 2 are active and the rest are queued.

Is that the expected behaviour for Storage SDK on Android? iOS SDK seems to be more permissive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the SDK according to my needs(increased concurrent threads limit) and used the SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Can you please share how you were able to do it?

Comment: Just cloned the official SDK code and created a snapshot with the modified value of the threads. If you have exactly the same requirement, get in touch with me at ciobanu.razvand@gmail.com and I can send the modified lib.

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior.

On mobile connections, uploads don't complete any faster with a high level of parallelism. All the uploads will compete for the same limited bandwidth.

You can see how the SDK works, since it's [open source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk).  Feel free to modify it as you see fit, so you can see if your benchmarks are better.  For feature requests, please [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: As 10 KB is the size of each file, won't be a better idea to be able to handle more than 2 threads in the same time ? What is taking the most time now is probably to make the connection between client and firebase. Starting let's say 10 in parallel would probably make things better as it's connecting to different endpoints in the same time. I mean it's probably not the bandwidth problem as it's the connection taking time.

Comment: As I said, feel free to modify the SDK to perform the way you would prefer, or file a feature request.  The SDK doesn't currently make any assumptions about the size of the file.  Most uploads are much larger.

Comment: any idea about how can I import the storage module into my project? Tried so many times but I always get dependencies problem. I copied the firebase-storage folder into my project, added the module and then compiling fails.